# Change order of two grid items

Tags: html, css

I got this grid with 4 divs inside

```css
.d-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-grid">
<div class="item-1"></div>
<div class="item-2"></div>
<div class="item-3"></div>
<div class="item-4"></div>

</div>
```

Then on my mobile view I want to change the order of the column 2 with 1. How can I do this? With flex I could do reverse-column, how can I swap item 2 with 1?

Comment: use order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties like: grid-column-start, grid-column-end, grid-row-start, grid-row-end, and position.

Example of code:

```
.item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Sk4tt/hqw0e4a7/)

If you want to learn more: [flex grid mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout)